# Is there popState to back browser history stack in AMP?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

Is there Any way to back browser history when use `AMP.pushState()`?
Is the `AMP.popState()` (or `window.history.back()`) function implemented in AMP project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AMP document](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/) `AMP.goBack` is a top-level action that navigates back in history.

> Note that it has some limitations: [#5225](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/5225)